# Terraform AWS ALB listener rules to microservices setup as ECS targets

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-application-load-balancer

To DevOps,
I have multiple services off an ALB and they are from an on-prem.
Can I have multiple redirect rules to a path of "/" to different services off the same ALB?
Such as

```
    Path "/test1" => Redirect to "/"  => Service1
    Path "/test2" => Redirect to "/"  => Service2
```

Service1 and Service2 are not listening on /test1 nor /test2.
Thanks,

Answer (score 4):

You can chose a target group based on [path conditions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-listeners.html#path-conditions) but ALBs do not currently handle rewriting paths.

Comment: Thanks, I can redirect to "/" and have that forward to a target group but not both.

Comment: correct.  you will have to do the rewrite on the receiving side or have the backend applications be aware of pathing (I'd recommend the latter)